# php error reporting - having trouble matching local & web server settings

Tags: php, error-handling

I'm trying to add a custom error handler to my site, but in doing so have discovered that my webhost's PHP error reporting settings and those of my localhost (default XAMPP) vary considerably.

While I thought I was programming to E_STRICT like a good little boy, adding the error handler to my webhost revealed craploads of Runtime Notices. Example:

```
Runtime notice
strtotime() [function.strtotime]: It is not safe to rely on the system's timezone
settings. Please use the date.timezone setting, the TZ environment variable or 
the date_default_timezone_set() function. In case you used any of those methods
and you are still getting this warning, you most likely misspelled the
timezone identifier. We selected 'America/Chicago' for 'CST/-6.0/no DST' instead
In /home/...
```

Clearly this isn't a red-alert, showstopping error. But what bothers me is that it doesn't show up on my localhost. I'd certainly like to improve my code by addressing these sorts of issues *if I could see them!*

I've looked through both `php.ini` files, and my webhost's setting is `error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` whereas mine was `error_reporting = E_STRICT`, which I had thought was better. However, changing mine to match and rebooting the server doesn't seem to have accomplished anything.

Could someone please point me in the right direction?

**EDIT** - it seems I didn't make myself clear. I know how to solve the problem the notice is finding. **MY PROBLEM** is that my development PHP and my webhost's PHP are not throwing the same level of errors. The webhost is reporting these runtime notices while my testbed does not. And I don't know how to make my testbed show these errors.

Comment: **why not to correct an error instead of altering reporting level??**

Comment: I **want** to correct the errors, but currently I can only see these error messages on the web host. Identical files on the localhost don't trip any errors, so I'm assuming there is a discrepancy in error reporting levels between the two servers. It's a bitch to debug if I can only do it on a live installation! :-(

Comment: I see now, took it wrong at first, sorry

Comment: are you sure you're editing the right php.ini file? setting the same error_reporting level and restarting the server should produce the same output, maybe find out the apache-loaded one in <?php phpinfo(); ?> ?

Comment: I used phpinfo. The webhost is running 5.2.15 from 2010/12/15 whereas my XAMPP installation is running 5.3.1, which is from 2009/11/20. I'm going to update the local version and see how it goes.

Comment: the output from phpinfo(), what's the value of the 'Loaded Configuration File' is this the same file that you're editing?

Comment: I was not able to update the local version. Crossing the streams `grin` is a bit trickier than I expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, E_STRICT is already highest of them. Keep it.
2. Your PHP version on localhost is outdated. Upgrade it.
3. Then add date_default_timezone_set() to the application's config file to make correction of this error portable.

Comment: as an alternative, put date.timezone = America/Chicago (or your timezone) in the php.ini file

Answer (score 1):

1. In php ini set `date.timezone = "America/New_York"`
2. In your code set `date_default_timezone_set()`
3. In .htaccess set `php_value date.timezone "America/New_York"`

Of caurse, `America/New_York` is example.